# Best common practice for data insert/update scripts in flyway

Tags: flyway

scenario:  I have two databases.

The first database is a blank database used for testing.  I essentially run flyway:migrate and build the database with complete schema and run my integration tests against that blank database.  Any data that the integration tests need are inserted before the tests are run.  Finally, the database is tore down by using flyway:clean to make sure the next build that comes through has a clean db to work with.

The second database has data in it.

Problem: The build fails in the integration phase because I have migration scripts that depends on data which database 1 doesn't have.  Basically I'm inserting data based on certain data existing in the db.

Is the best common practice for flyway to only have ddl change type migration scripts and no data insert/update scripts?

Comment: If it's seed data (reference data, lookup data), I'd say that this should be added in a migration script.

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding your reference data behind an IF statement in an afterMigrate callback:

http://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

In the best case you add it as a migration and change it in the future via migrations. Including production. Things can be more complicated if that data can be changed on real environments by other means. In such case I would personally prefer to have a (shared) test fixture to insert the sample data.